# Google Calendar API CalendarList.list() returns a weird object - JS

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I want to get the list of the calendars of a user with JS by using CalendarList.list() as stated in the documentation. But for me I only get a weird object as response, that always looks like this:

```js
{
    "Yd": 1,
    "mb": {
        "Vf": null,
        "yh": {
            "path": "/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList",
            "method": "GET",
            "params": {},
            "headers": {},
            "root": "https://www.googleapis.com",
            "apiId": "calendar:v3"
        },
        "Cl": "auto",
        "G_": false,
        "VN": false,
        "aQ": false
    }
}
```

I'm using the standard code from the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js) which works fine for me, only this one request returns a weird result.

It looks like this in my code (just the part of it that should be interesting):

```js
function initClient() {
      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: SCOPES
      }).then(function() {
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
      }, function(error) {
        changeSpanText(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
      });
    }


function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
      if (isSignedIn) {
        authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
        signoutButton.style.display = 'flex';
        changeSpanText(" You have been logged in succesfully");
        console.log(gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list());
      } else {
        authorizeButton.style.display = 'flex';
        signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        changeSpanText("");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your modified code to list the calendars? Also, if you use the [try this api here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/list) do you get a different response?

Comment: @YancyMelany I've added my code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue using the code shared and effectively, this is something related to how the response is output to the console, making a few modifications like below:

```
            function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
            if (isSignedIn) {
                authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
                signoutButton.style.display = 'flex';
                gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list({}).then(function (response) { // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                    console.log("Response", JSON.stringify(response, null,2));
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error("Execute error", err);
                });

            } else {
                authorizeButton.style.display = 'flex';
                signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
```

I got a successful and correctly formatted output:

[image]

If instead of the entire output you wish to have only some of the detail fields like 'summary' you can do the below:

```
            function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
            if (isSignedIn) {
                authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
                signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
                listCalends();

            } else {
                authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
                signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
         function listCalends() {
            gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list().then(function (response) {
               var calendar = response.result.items;
               var strinx = calendar;
               console.log('Calendars owned by this user are: ');
               for (let index = 0 ; index < strinx.length; index++) {                    
                  console.log( strinx[index]['summary']);                      
               } 
            });
        }
```

#### Recommendation:

If you are unsure as how to go about doing something with Google APIs using Javascript I encourage you to use their [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/list?apix=true#try-it) and click on the 'Javascript' option where it will show you how the request was made so you can have some reference for future projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and for the recommendation, I didn't notice this before!